# Hide lightning component from community guest user

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components

We have a community built using the Napili templates that contain a few custom made lightning components. The issue is all of the custom components display to guest community users. Depending on the data used in the component and the permissions attached to them, some of the components return empty values making it look like they don't work while others will function just fine. To add to the issue, the standard components either are hidden on the page or redirect to the login page depending on the page and component used, making the custom components behavior seem even more out of place.

I've looked at the options for [access in `aura:component`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_components.htm) but the only options appear to be 'public' and 'global', neither seeming to do what I want.

Instead of relying on the data to be the limiting factor for a components use to a guest community user, is there a way that I can just hide the entire component for this type of user?

Answer (score 2):

You can use aura if to conditionally render elements for Guest User versus other profiles

```
 public class RichTextController {
   @AuraEnabled
   public static boolean isrendered(){
    boolean isrendered = true;
    if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Guest') {
        isrendered = false;
    } 
    return isrendered;
   }
}
```

The lightning component code at the front end will look like below

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="RichTextController">
    <aura:attribute name="rendered" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.rendered}">

   </aura:renderIf>
  </aura:component>
```

The Js controller

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    var action = component.get('c.isrendered');
    action.setCallback(this,function(result){
        component.set('v.rendered',result.getReturnValue());
         console.log(result.getReturnValue());
    });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [Criteria Based Audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0) which offers you the possibility of creating page variations depending on the current user profile. This is an OOTB functionality that the napili template offers for you to change what components or layout is displayed.

Since the Guest User licence cannot be selected from the profiles view when creating a page variation, set a Default view with "no profiles" and for the rest of the profiles, set a page variation with your custom components.

Comment: Does this allow the guest user to be specified as an audience? I am having trouble finding the guest profile in the list for an audience.

Comment: Indeed, it is not under the options even when selecting the all profiles, in that case,  you would need to default the view for what unauthenticated users see (default: guest user license) and when an authenticated user is on the community, set all their profiles to see the custom components.

Comment: This seems like a huge oversight from Salesforce, hopefully they will fix this.

Comment: Indeed, but the process remains pretty straightforward. Just inverse the logic. ;)

Comment: Did you manage to make it work @dsharrison?

Comment: Yes, but it seems like this inverse setup is a maintenance nightmare. If a new profile is added to the community all pages have to be updated to show the non-guest view for that profile.

Comment: =( , not sure if this is as designed or just a missing feature in communities. Would probably have to check with someone from SF. But definitely a pain...